# Tower of Hanoi simulation

Tags: java, algorithm, tower-of-hanoi

I've just implemented a simulation of tower of hanoi in Java. Any suggestions are welcomed. Here's my code:

```
static class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int data){
    this.data = data;
    }
}


static class Stack{
    Node top;
    String stackName;

    public Stack(String name){
        stackName = name;
    }

    public String getStackName(){
        return stackName;
    }

    public void push(int data){
        if(top==null){
            top = new Node(data);
            System.out.println("Created Stack, pushing : " + data);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Pushed : " + data);
            Node someNode = new Node(data);
            someNode.next = top;
            top = someNode;
        }
    }

    public Node pop(){
        if(top==null){
            System.out.println("Error : Stack is empty!");
            return new Node(-1);
        }
        if(top.next==null){
            Node toRet = new Node(top.data);
            System.out.println("Stack " + this.stackName + " will be emptied now");
            top = null;
            return toRet;
        }
        Node temp = top;
        top = top.next;
        System.out.println("Popped : " + temp.data);
        return temp;
    }

    public String getTop(){
        if(top==null){
            return "Stack is empty";
        }
        return String.valueOf(top.data);
    }

    public void pushTo(Stack anotherStack){
        System.out.println("Pushed " + this.top.data + " from " + this.stackName + " to " + anotherStack.stackName);
        Node toPush = this.pop();
        anotherStack.push(toPush.data);
    }

}


public static void tower(int number, Stack stackFrom, Stack stackInter, Stack stackTo){
    if(number == 1){
        stackFrom.pushTo(stackTo);
    }else{
        tower(number-1, stackFrom, stackTo, stackInter);
        stackFrom.pushTo(stackTo);
        tower(number-1, stackInter, stackFrom, stackTo);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack myStack = new Stack("A");
    myStack.push(10);
    myStack.push(15);
    myStack.push(20);
    myStack.push(25);
    Stack anotherStack = new Stack("B");
    Stack yetAnotherStack = new Stack("C");
    tower(4, myStack, anotherStack, yetAnotherStack);
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: explicitly state your goals - in particular comment your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Use `java.util.Deque`

Instead of implementing your own stack,
it's better and easier to use the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) in the JDK.
(Not [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), as the JavaDoc explains, `Deque` is recommended.
Thanks [@greybeard](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/93149/greybeard) for the tip!)

#### Naming

In this game there are discs and towers (or sticks, rods, pegs).
It would be better to call them that way instead of `Node` and `Stack`.

`tower` is a poor name for moving discs.
In general, verbs are best for method names.
In this example `move` would be natural.

#### Alternative implementation

With the above suggestions applied,
the implementation becomes:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;

public class Hanoi {

    private static class Tower {

        private final String name;
        private final Deque<Integer> stack;

        public Tower(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        }

        public void add(int... discs) {
            for (int disc : discs) {
                stack.push(disc);
            }
        }

        public int size() {
            return stack.size();
        }

        public void moveOneDisc(Tower to) {
            System.out.println("Pushed " + this.stack.peek() + " from " + this.name + " to " + to.name);
            to.stack.push(this.stack.pop());
        }

        private void moveDiscs(int count, Tower mid, Tower to) {
            if (count == 1) {
                moveOneDisc(to);
            } else {
                moveDiscs(count - 1, to, mid);
                moveOneDisc(to);
                mid.moveDiscs(count - 1, this, to);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tower from = new Tower("A");
        from.add(10, 15, 20, 25);
        Tower mid = new Tower("B");
        Tower to = new Tower("C");
        from.moveDiscs(from.size(), mid, to);
    }
}
```

Some other improvements:

- Moved the `tower` method inside the `Tower` class and renamed to `move`
- `Tower.add` accepts varargs, for conveniently adding multiple discs
- `Tower.size` to know the number of discs on a tower
- The method names of `Tower` are all in the language of the problem domain, not the implementation (implementation details are well hidden)

Comment: From the Java SE docs: [prefer Deque over Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), the crux being _legacy classes_ won't go away, hogging names that would make perfect interface names. Toyed with the code presented: [Lucas on Ideone](http://ideone.com/YhJ9wQ). Not convinced `moveTo()` should be a member of `Tower`, let alone  `move()`. Like `if (0 < count) { move(count-1, …); trace(); to.push(from.pop()); move(count-1, …); }` better.

Comment: @greybeard Aw, I always forget that about `Stack`, thanks for the reminder. The example implementation is not really meant to be perfect. But inspired by your work on Ideone I added some improvements, which you were right to point out. Btw I disagree with Tower extending ArrayDeque, because a Tower is not meant as an ArrayDeque. So I think composition is better here than inheritance.